# Easy to use, standalone web user interface libraries

Tags: spring-mvc, client-side, web-frontend

I use  asp.net, jsf, jsp and now spring mvc. Spring mvc with rest is perfect solution for server side development but I still have problem with client side. I know a little JavaScript and CSS and developing user interface consumes much time. I wonder if there is an easy to use framework for client side development with spring mvc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try extjs.  I think extjs is a product that is best suited for people like you - that is someone who feels comfortable on the backend, but does not want to bother much with designing widgets, jquery components and working with css.

With extjs you will get rich components right out of the box.

However, you might have to reexamine your architecture.  More than likely, you will probably use the spring mvc layer to produce some sort of restful api, or json over http scenario.  In other words, the html markup will purely be managed by extjs and it's data will come from the server.

It is a javascript framework, so there will be a bit of learning curve but I think the structure of extjs mvc projects is pretty easy to grasp.

Alternatively, you can try an implementation of JSF such as RichFaces. You will again get rich web 2.0 like components with very little need to write javascript.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have already use rich faces .I find it hard to use.Primefaces more attractive choice ,i think.But is it possible use jsf with spring mvc .

Comment: Currently I am trying  to use spring mvc with rest and json for data transfer.But client side development taking considerable time with jquery ui .

Comment: by the way, i've never heard of primefaces.  Just checked it out, it seems pretty cool.  Thanks.

Comment: I check  extjs and its really cool but license issue bothering me.My company will not want to open   code or pay .